# How import logs from gcp projet?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, logging

I read some documentation on internet official and non official and i'm currently unable to import the logs from bigquery like  "bigquery_resource"  (for getting all my insert, update, merge ... processing on my gcp project ) from a gcp project where i'm owner with python on my local.

Mandatory prerequisite :

- Only use the scripts to read and catch the logs with a filter without creating CF, data in bucket, manual action from user on the gcp project etc...
- Using a service account in the process
- Import the bigquery logs from the gcp on a local when i execute my script python

Here the code below where i try to get the logs  :

```
import google.protobuf
from google.cloud.bigquery_logging_v1 import AuditData
import google.cloud.logging
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="C:\\mypath\\credentials.json"

project_id = os.environ["GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"] = "project1"



yesterday = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(days=2)
time_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"

filter_str = (
    f'logName="projects/{project_id}/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"'
    f' AND resource.type="bigquery_resource"'
    f' AND timestamp>="{yesterday.strftime(time_format)}"'
)


client = google.cloud.logging.Client(project="project1")


for entry in client.list_entries(filter_=filter_str):
    decoded_entry = entry.to_api_repr()
    #print(decoded_entry)
    print(entry) #the same output as print(decoded_entry)



open("C:\\mypath\\logs.txt", "w").close()
with open("C:\\mypath\\logs.txt", "w") as f:
    for entry in client.list_entries(filter_=filter_str):

        f.write(entry)
```

Unfortunately , it doesn't work(and my code is messy),  i get a ProtobufEntry with the var entry like below and i don't know how get my data from my gcp project in a proper way.

[image: My output]

All the help is welcome ! (please don't answer me with a **deprecated answer** from openaichatgpt )

Comment: chatgpt is temporarily banned in stackoverflow. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how i export my logs without creating bucket, sink, pubsub, cloud function, table in bigquery etc..

=> Only *1 Service account* with rights on my project and *1 script .py* on my local and added an option in the python script for scan only bigquery ressource during the last hour.

I add the path of gcloud because i have some problem with path in my envvar in my local with the popen lib, maybe you won't need to do it.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import json

from google.cloud.bigquery_logging_v1 import AuditData
import google.cloud.logging
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="C:\\Users\\USERAAAA\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\credentials.json"

gcloud_path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\\gcloud.cmd"
process = Popen([gcloud_path, "logging", "read", "resource.type=bigquery_resource AND logName=projects/PROJECTGCP1/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access", "--freshness=1h"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
output_str = stdout.decode()

# data string into a a file
with open("C:\\Users\\USERAAAA\\Documents\\Python_Scripts\\testes.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(output_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this as follows:

Create a dedicated logging sink for BigQuery logs:

```
gcloud logging sinks create my-example-sink bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/my-project-id/datasets/auditlog_dataset \
    --log-filter='protoPayload.metadata."@type"="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.BigQueryAuditMetadata"'
```

The above command will create logging sink in a dataset named `auditlog_dataset` that only includes `BigQueryAuditMetadata` messages. Refer [BigQueryAuditMetadata](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/BigQueryAuditMetadata) for all the events which are captured as part of GCP AuditData.

Create a service account and give access to above created dataset.

For creating service account [refer here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) and for granting access to dataset [refer here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/control-access-to-resources-iam#bq_3).

Use this service account to authenticate from your local environment and query the above created dataset using [BigQuery Python client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) to get filtered BigQuery data.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

# Select rows from log dataset
QUERY = (
    'SELECT name FROM `MYPROJECTID.MYDATASETID.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_activity`'
    'LIMIT 100')
query_job = client.query(QUERY)  # API request
rows = query_job.result()  # Waits for query to finish

for row in rows:
    print(row.name)
```

Also, you can [query the audit tables from the console](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui) directly.

Reference [BigQuery audit logging](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs).

Another option is to use [Python Script](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/write-query-log-entries-python) to query log events. And one more option is to use [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) to route logs to external (out of gcp) clients.

I mostly prefer to keep the filtered logs in dedicated [Log Analytics](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/devops-sre/introducing-cloud-loggings-log-analytics-powered-by-big-query) bucket and query as per needs and create custom [log based metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics) using Cloud Monitoring. Moving logs out of GCP may incur [network egress](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing) charges, refer the documentation, if you are querying large volume of data.

Comment: Hello, 

thanks for your comment, but the only part that match with my question is your link on python script , but in this link , i need to create sink , bucket in my projet  etc... it is what i want to avoid, i just need to catch my logs, because some projects are highly restricted , and i can't give some roles to my service account.

ps : The other options you give are good but i can't create dataset, table, pubsub event etc... for the same reasons i give before.